# Icons for Visual Studio 2017 Solution Explorer file types

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, solution-explorer

I have this icon

[image: icon in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio]

in my Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 and I don't know what that means.

It is not a single file it seems like a whole remote project. When I open it it is shown in Object Browser. But if I try to go to reference of classes inside this it open .cs file.

I am wondering what this icon means. I would be glad to see all icons Visual Studio provides for program types like C#, this icon, reference... Is there any list of those icons for Solution Explorer with short description of meaning?

I tried to find out what that icons means but I was unable to find any list at all. I checked out this "file" and I got multiple files (with one .cs, one .map and one .wsdl file donwloaded along with multiple database context files.

Can someone explain what this icon means or even better provide list of icons that can appear in Visual Studio Solution Explorer with a short description what it means?

Comment: In VS 2022 I can hover my mouse over a button in the toolbar and it will show a tooltip with the command name and keyboard shortcut. Have you tried this in V 2017 - I imagine that this feature of VS will have existed then.